# Heroku. Request taking 100ms, intermittently Times out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, load-testing, thin

After performing load testing against an app hosted on Heroku, I am finding that the most DB intensive request takes 50-200ms depending upon load. It never gets slower, no matter the load. However, seemingly at random, the request will outright timeout (30s or more).

On Heroku, why might a relatively high performing query/request work perfectly 8 times out of 10 and outright timeout 2 times out of 10 as load increases?

If this is starting to seem like a question for Heroku itself, I'm looking to first answer the question of whether "bad code" could somehow cause this issue -- or if it is clearly a problem on their end.

A bit more info:

Multiple Dynos
Cedar Stack
Dedicated Heroku DB (16 connections, 1.7 GB RAM, 1 comp. unit)
Rails 3.0.7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have multiple dynos and a dedicated DB instance and are paying hundreds of dollars a month for their service, you should ask Heroku

Edit:  I should have added that when you check your logs, you can look for a line that says "routing"  That is the Heroku routing layer that takes HTTP request and sends them to your app.  You can add those up to see how much time is being spent outside your app.  Unfortunately I don't know how easy it is to get large volumes of those logs for a load test.